# confusion determining element number of an array

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, sizeof

I've heard from my lecturer, sizeof(some pointer) always equal in a machine. For example, if it is 64 bit all pointers are 8 byte, in 32 bit 4 byte. So, I like to use `sizeof` when I want to specify size of an array like

```
int arr[] = {2, 5, -1, 10, 9};
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)
```

I assume that above code an `int` takes `4`, so `20/4` gives number of elements for `arr`.

```
int arr[] = {2, 5, -1, 10, 9};
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int*)
```

I also assume that `sizeof(some pointer)` takes `4`, so `20/4` again gives number of elements for `arr`.

I'm confused that when I apply it for a `double` array. I think it shouldn't work. But, it works.

```
double arr[] = {2, 5, -1, 10, 9};
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(double*);
```

If every pointers take same size in a machine, how can be the result right? Can be the question explained?
Edit

> I mixed up division by *arr and double pointer

Comment: Maybe you should post what you expect and why, and what you get. Because as it stands your question isn't very clear.

Comment: where are you hard to understand?

Comment: Only what you expect and why, and what you get, and what you're actually asking.

Comment: I have written I don't understand at which point you stuck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size of a pointer is not the size of the type of the elements in the `double` array, because the elements are `double`s not pointers.

When you apply `sizeof` to an array it gives the size of the array ***in bytes***, in case of

```
double arr[] = {2, 5, -1, 10, 9};
```

it's

```
5 * sizeof(double)
```

and `sizeof(double) != sizeof(double *)`. So to actually get the number of elements in the array you need

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(double);
```

but to make it more maintainable, you can just ask for the size of the type of the elements like this

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
```

or

```
sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Also, do not rely on this method to determine the number of elements in an array. Note that at runtime there is no way to know that from the array itself in [c](/questions/tagged/c), since it's not stored with the array. You need to store the value if you want to keep track of the number of elements.

While this might seem annoying when you first think of it, with the experience you should learn that, it's better this way. Because it gives you complete control over what data your program has to handle, and once you get used to it, it will become very hard to trust languages that just give you the length of the array like python's `len` operator.

Comment: @cup You soudn't delete your answer, but you should not cast the result to `int`, may I know why you do that?

Comment: Isn't `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(double) <= sizeof(double*)` and similarly for other data types?

Comment: `sizeof(int)` might very well be less or equal than `sizeof(int *)` but `sizeof(double)` is certainly larger or equal than `sizeof(double *)`.